# Change button attr on keyup dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I'm working on search, and currently toggling an input field with the search icon. By default the icon is wrapped in a button element with type button so it will not submit the form.

I want to validate if text has been entered and then change the type of the button so it will then submit on next click of the icon.

Here's my code so far

```
// Mobile Search UI 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobile-btn-search').click(function(){
    $('.mobile-input').toggle('slow');
  });

  $('.mobile-input').keyup(function(){
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $('.mobile-btn-search').attr('type', 'submit');
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Typo: `$('mobile-btn-search')` should presumably be `$('.mobile-btn-search')`

Comment: Thanks, even after that change my attribute isn't changing when a value is entered into the input field.

Comment: `$('mobile-input')` -> `$('.mobile-input')` too. Although I'd follow @ZakariaAcharki's suggestion of enabling/disabling the button instead of dynamically changing its `type`, as the latter can cause issues in some browsers.

Comment: That won't work. You can see my comment to him on the scenario.

Comment: In which case I'd suggest amending your UI, as changing `type` dynamically isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AybAX/50/)**.

You probably getting the following error :

> **Uncaught Error:** type property can't be changed

Check the console please.

You should use `.prop()` instead :

```
$('.mobile-btn-search').prop('type')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That won't work, because I have to toggle the input field back and forth with .mobile-btn-search. If the button is disabled then I will not be able to toggle the input field.

Comment: Do you have really to use one button for two actions ? if someone trying to search with empty field then the field will be toggled by the search button?

Comment: Yes field will be toggled by search button if no value is entered. In this scenario on mobile, one button for toggle and search works for layout. I know I could accomplish it by having another submit button hidden with the input field until it is toggled. But I'm trying to write the logic to make it happen with one button.

Comment: Ok, have you checked the typo in `$('mobile-input')` also? by adding the dot `$('.mobile-input')`

Comment: Yes I caught that once I posted it. No difference made with changing the attribute on that button dynamically.

Comment: Ok, you should just to use `prop()` instead, check my update.